# How to test in-app purchase ios

Tags: ios, ionic2, in-app-purchase

I built my app with ionic, and now I am ready to test it.
I am able to sign it correctly with certificate and provisioning profile from my apple developer account.

In my app I added also in-app purchase. I used the cordova plugin.

Next I enabled in Capabilities section, the In-App Purchase menu.

Then, in iTunesConnect I created a product, and once did it, I uploaded again a new build and connected my app with this new build. Keep in mind that I set also the product in the tab App Store in iTunesConnect.

For now I am using Test Flight to test the app, and it works fine

In iTunesConnect, in the "in-app purchase" section, I have this notice:

"*Your first in-app purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
Once your binary has been uploaded and your first in-app purchase has been submitted for review, additional in-app purchases can be submitted using the table below*."

In the In-App Purchase section, I can see only one product with status "ready to submit", and I am not able to submit in some way...

I followed some help on line, but with no success.

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: As soon as you will submit your app for review IAP product would also submitted for review.

Comment: but I have to submit to review the whole app? You mean, in the App Store section I have to click on the Submit to Review button? I don't want to publish the app in the app store

Comment: and also, how to test the in-app purchase?

Comment: Don't worry about the IAP product "Ready to Submit" status. Your IAP product is ready to test now.

Answer (score 0):

Login to `itunesconnect.com -> User and roles -> Sandbox Testers`

Add a sandbox account -> install your app in device -> Sign In with the Sandbox account in your device -> Test your app.

Comment: I already created the test sandbox account. I installed the app from xcode in my device, launched the app, but I have this message: WARNING: ios -> product it.xxx.xxx is NOT valid. {"id":"it.oandsi.fotosa.products.event","alias":"it.xxx.xxx","type":"consumable","state":"invalid","title":null,"description":null,"priceMicros":null,"price":null,"currency":null,"loaded":true,"canPurchase":false,"owned":false,"downloading":false,"downloaded":false,"additionalData":null,"transaction":null,"valid":false}

Comment: Have you added all the information for IAP product in iTunes? If not the fill it. Some time it take times after you made update in iTunes.

Comment: and also, when I log into my device with the sandbox account, I got this message: At moment this apple ID cannot be used in Itunes Store. Please try again (I translated from italy message but the sense is this)

Comment: Can you try remove app again fro device. Just clean it and reinstall.

Comment: the problem is that the sandbox account, doesn't work on my device.. I am not able to connect with it in my device... for the message above...

Comment: Just logout from iTunes in device and then try login using sandbox account.

Comment: Yes, I did it with no success: Settings -> iTunes Store and App Store -> clicked on ID -> sign out. Then login again with the sandbox account, but I have the message: At moment this apple ID cannot be used in Itunes Store. Please try again

Comment: Do it like: Logout from iTunes and leave it blank. @Gjord83 And then go to buy IAP product. It will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170856/discussion-between-gjord83-and-dheeraj-d).